# How to include files in Cstom recipe for yocto build

Tags: go, copy, yocto, recipe

Hi all I'm new to Yocto and trying to build my first recipe, I have a custom layer which shows up and installs correctly on my system "colibri-imx6ull" but I cannot see any results of my recipes work. Bitbake seems to build them but maybe I've misunderstood something in the build process. I have a longtime goal of installing Golang and a few custom scripts but currently, I'm not even able to copy a simple text file.

Version available is
Toradex (2.8)   v2017.12    rocko (2.4)

I have added my layer to oe-core/build/conf/bblayers.conf

```
${TOPDIR}/../layers/meta-hydroware \
```

I have a layer configuration file avalible at

```
/layers/meta-hydroware/recipes-golang/conf/layer.conf
```

Containing the following

```
BBPATH := "${BBPATH}:${LAYERDIR}"
BBFILES := "${BBFILES} ${LAYERDIR}/recipes-*/*/*.bb \ 
       ${LAYERDIR}/recipes-*/*/*.bbappend"

BBFILE_COLLECTIONS += "golang"
BBFILE_PATTERN_golang := "^${LAYERDIR}/" 
BBFILE_PRIORITY_golang := "105"
```

It's included in the list of layers when building so hopefully it works.
Firstly I'm just trying to get anything to copy anywhere into my build and I've tried to use this recipe to copy a simple text file but it does not show up.

My recipe file "golang.bb" is located in

```
/layers/meta-hydroware/recipes-golang/golang/golang.bb
```

and the text file is located in

```
/layers/meta-hydroware/recipes-golang/golang/files
```

This is the content of my golang.bb

```
SUMMARY = "Provides GO"
DESCRIPTION = "Tools for runnings and compiling GO"

SRC_URI =   "file://readme.txt"

LICENSE = "CLOSED"

S = "${WORKDIR}"
FILES_${PN} = ""
ALLOW_EMPTY_${PN} = "1"

do_install() {
    install -m 0755 -d ${D}${bindir} ${D}${bindir}/go
    mkdir ~/usr/bin/go
    cp -a --no-preserve=ownership ${WORKDIR}/* ${D}${bindir}/go/
}
```

My goal is to install golang which is available in the same folder as the textfile

```
 /layers/meta-hydroware/recipes-golang/golang/files/go1.11.2.linux-armv6l.tar.gz
```

My first goal is to be able to find the text file somewhere on my installed machine, the second goal is to install go. Is there anything wrong with my recipe which prevents it from placing the file?

Are there any additional things I need to do in order to handle to install a .tar.gz file? or do do_install() understand what to do?

Thanks for your answers
//Confused newbie who spend too many days on this already ^^

Comment: Parthiban has given you hints on the recipe writing, I'll just comment on Go: packaging development tools can be very tricky... luckily you'll almost never have to do it as someone else has done it for you. In this case the go recipe can be found in openembedded-core itself: Just add the go package to your image and you're done (the one in rocko is a little older than 1.11 though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple improvements to the recipe,

```
SUMMARY = "Provides GO"
DESCRIPTION = "Tools for runnings and compiling GO"

SRC_URI =   "file://readme.txt"

LICENSE = "CLOSED"
S = "${WORKDIR}"

do_install() {
    install -d ${D}${bindir}/go
    install -Dm 0755 ${WORKDIR}/readme.txt ${D}${bindir}/go
}

FILES_${PN} = "${bindir}/*"
```

The above recipe should work if its included directly into image using `IMAGE_INSTALL_append` in local.conf or image recipe or some other package `RDEPENDS` on this package.

Corrections done:

1. You don't need to allow the empty package
2. `FILES_${PN}` should carry the list files you want to install
3. `install -d` creates the directory and `install -Dm` to copy it. You don't need to use `cp` or `mkdir` inside the recipe.

Comment: defining the **FILES_${PN}** it's not needed, this is the default value from - **meta/conf/bitbake.conf** (it's wise to know about this configuration file I think).

Comment: Thanks for the help so far! I tried the updated recipe you provided but still no result. I was checking the /usr/bin, /bin/ for a go directory but none was to be found and no textfile either. I've tried to bitbake both the recipe and the image again with bitbake -k golang aswell as bitbake -k hydroware-image it builds in both cases but i cannot find the file... Is there anything else that needs to be done to include the recipe or do I have to do anything during the build progress? or do the files just hide somewhere else?